# MarkLogic XML query to restart forest (with additional logic )

Tags: marklogic-10

currently we have below script - where the "@p_replica" is passed from front-end. Below xml works fine for a single forest restart.
cat ml_RestartReplica.sql
xquery version "1.0-ml";
--@p_replica
xdmp:forest-restart(xdmp:forest($p_replica));

I would need help to start n replica forests at once -- i can pass all n (or less ) replica names to - @p_replica. Now the xml logic has to figure out a way and find the value of n (based on the commas eg: Replica_1,Replica_2,Replica_3  here n is 3 )
and the xml query should like this below

xquery version "1.0-ml";
--@p_replica
xdmp:forest-restart((xdmp:forest("Replica_1"),xdmp:forest("Replica_1"),xdmp:forest("Replica_2"),xdmp:forest("Replica_3")));

currently we have below script - where the "@p_replica" is passed from front-end. Below xml works fine for a single forest restart.
cat ml_RestartReplica.sql
xquery version "1.0-ml";
--@p_replica
xdmp:forest-restart(xdmp:forest($p_replica));